# VBA Loop through, Find unique values, assign to variable, match to another variable

Tags: vba, loops, duplicates

Column A contains names. Column B contains values. Each name in column A has many values in column B. I want to make sure every unique name in column A contains a value of "1600460116" in B. If a name in column A does not have a value of "1600460116", then I need to highlight it.

So far, I have highlighted column A and B when the value of "1600460116" appears:

```
    For i = 2 To sh4lRow
        If InStr((sh4.Cells(i, dealID)), "1600460116") > 0 Then
            sh4.Cells(i, dealID).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            sh4.Cells(i, ioNameB).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else: sh4.Cells(i, dealID).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    Next i
```

(note: ioName B is column A and dealID is column B)

I'm thinking I need to loop through each loop through the names and put unique names into a variable. Then I'm thinking I need to loop through the highlighted column B values and put those unique A names into another variable. Then I need to find where the lists don't match up.

Can someone please help me finish this code?

Here is what my excel file looks like: [excel here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXAR5.png)

Comment: Why not use Conditional formatting?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'many values in column B' - do you mean there are repeated rows for an entry in A each with a different value in B or do you mean there is one row for a particular entry in A with lots of different values in the SAME cell in column B?

Comment: Yes sorry for not clarifying. There are repeated rows for an entry A each with a different value in B

Answer (score 0):

OK - Couple of points here, I've used an oldschool EXCEL FORMULA in a new column to create strings that combine colA and colB - the new col is variable x, which you will have to set a value for in any empty column on the worksheet (it will be deleted afterwards). With this new col x I've made a new range which is just row2 to lastrow in the new column.

Once that string concat is in the new column it cycles through the names in colA and checks if the name+1600460116 exists anywhere in the new column. If it does not, it highlights the name black (color 2).

Aftewards it deletes any formula from the new column range. Hope this makes sense!

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim newRange As Range

With sh4
Set newRange = .Range(Cells(2, x).Address & ":" & Cells(sh4lRow, x).Address)
    newRange.Formula = ("=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()," & ioNameB & "))&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()," & dealID & "))")
    For i = 2 To sh4lRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(newRange, .Cells(i, 1).Value & "*1600460116*") = 0 Then
            .Cells(i, ioNameB).Interior.Color = 2
        End If
    Next i
    newRange.ClearContents
End With
```

I use this method rather than cycling through all rows for each row because it's a lot quicker!

Comment: I see what happens. It loops through and if there are 0 values of "1600460116" (no matter which name) then everything is highlighted. Otherwise, if there is at least 1 value of "1600460116" in column B then nothing is highlighted.

Comment: Do I need to add a "for each" for each unique value in ioNameB?

Comment: Are you using the code from this new answer? I've just tested it and it's working fine. The old one I first provided had a mistake in it but this one above is working ok for me!

Comment: Yes, I'm using the code above. Does it matter if the Name (column A) has underscores?

Comment: I put a link in the original question for what my excel file looks like. I used the above code to see if it would highlight any Name that did not have "1600460116." I also tried adding asterisk ("*1600460116*") to try and find the cells that contained that value but had other values in the dealID column (e.g. [{"ABC":"1600460116","price":"0.0"}]). Both did not work.

Comment: Try changing the line `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(newRange, .Cells(i, 1).Value & "1600460116") = 0 Then` to `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(newRange, .Cells(i, 1).Value & "*1600460116*") = 0 Then` I've put an asterisk on either side of the 1600460116.

Comment: If there is one cell that contains "1600460116", then nothing is highlighted (even if only one of the many names have this one cell). If none of the cells contain "1600460116" then everything is highlighted.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry. This was now my fault in not being able to count apparently. I changed column positions so had to change the code slightly. Thank you so much for your help here - the above code works perfectly with the asterisks when name is column 1.

Comment: Ha, don't worry about it, I do that sorta thing on a daily basis! Glad the code is now working. If I change the answer to include the asterisks you can click the tick on the left to show this answer's solved if you like ;)